# Return the maximum element of an indexed object in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I return the index of the maximum element in an indexed object in Mathematica?

For example, I have an indexed object numbers[i] that contains an array of randomly generated numbers. number[1]=3, number[2]=1, number[3]=17, etc.  How do I return the index number of the element in number[i] that contains the largest value in the object? In this case, I would want a function that returns 3, because number[3] contains 17, which is the largest value in the object.  Thanks!

Comment: Absent any information about the relationship between indices and values you would examine each element in turn and keep a record of the index and value of the largest found.

Comment: If you have 30 values, what about `Module[{dsl=Array[number,30]}, First@Position[dsl,Max[dsl]]]`  ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll@n;
n[1] = 3;
n[2] = 1;
n[3] = 17;
n[4] = 5;
SortBy[DownValues[n][[All, 1, 1, 1]], n] // Last
```

> 3

If you have upgraded to Mathematica 10, you might consider whether an `Association` would meet your needs.

By the way, there is a [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site. :)